# Compiler says variable is undeclared even though it is declared

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

when i try to run this code i get the error: error: 'list1' undeclared (first use in this function). But i have declared the variable in main(), I also tried declaring it at the top, under text1,text2 and count. But then it said "initialzer element not constant". I've tried googling it but with no luck. btw the code isn't finished yet but i cant get past this error and just want to fix it.
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *text1 = "This is a string.";
char *text2 = "Yet another thing.";
int *count = 0;


void printlist(const int* lst){
  printf("ASCII codes and corresponding characters.\n");
  while(*lst != 0){
    printf("0x%03X '%c' ", *lst, (char)*lst);
    lst++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void endian_proof(const char* c){
  printf("\nEndian experiment: 0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x\n",
         (int)*c,(int)*(c+1), (int)*(c+2), (int)*(c+3));

}

void copycodes(char *text, int *list, int *counter){
    while(*text != 0){
        *list = *text;
        list++;
        text++;
    }
}

void work(){
    copycodes(&text1, &list1, &count);
}

int main(void){
  int *list1 = (int *)(malloc(80));
  int *list2 = (int *)(malloc(80));
  work();

  printf("\nlist1: ");
  printlist(list1);
  printf("\nlist2: ");
  printlist(list2);
  printf("\nCount = %d\n", count);

  endian_proof((char*) &count);
}
```

Comment: What is declared in the `main` stays in the `main`... It is a local variable, and cannot be referenced in other functions.

Comment: As has been pointed out, you cannot access a local variable in main() elsewhere. You could use your global declaration as before, the error means that you declared it incorrectly. Fix that and you'll be good.

Comment: You are already passing it to `copycodes`, pass it to the `work` as well, so it knows what it is and can pass to `copycodes`. Also, malloc allocates memory in bytes, not in number of array elements. 80 bytes would be enough to store 20 `int`s there. If you are already aware of this and want to store 20 `int`s, use a syntax like `malloc( 20*sizeof(int) )` and let the compiler deal with size of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EugeneSh. said, the variables `list1` and `list2` are local to `main()`, and thus aren't in scope for the other functions. While you could make the globals by simply initializing them to `NULL` and then setting them in `main()`, it would make more sense to pass `list1` as an argument to `work()`:

```
void work(int* list){
    copycodes(text1, list, count);
}
```

A few things to take note of:

- You do not need or want to cast the return value from `malloc()` (or `calloc()` for that matter). This is an exception to the usual rule regarding casting pointers.
- As @melonduofromage said, you would need to use the `sizeof(int)` to tell `malloc()` how large the elements being allocated are. Conversely, you could use `calloc()` instead, which is specifically meant to allocate arrays.

  `list1 = calloc(20, sizeof(int));`
- When passing a pointer to a function which accepts a pointer argument, you do not want or need to use the reference (`&`) operator for the pointer in question. That would only be needed if you were passing a pointer to a pointer argument.
- As a general rule, it is better to avoid globals unless the alternative is more confusing. In this case, you would need to pass more arguments to various functions, but the improved decomposition would make it worth it IMAO.
- Also as a general rule, if you find yourself using the pattern `var1`, `var2`, `var3`... `varN`, then you should should either bundle the variables into an array if they are related to each other, or else find more descriptive names if they are not.

Comment: As a note, C++ doesn't allow assigning `void*` return of `malloc` to anything else, so if OP is using a C++ compiler, he has to, and there are a lot of people writing C and compiling with C++ compliers.

Comment: @melonduofromage, if the OP thinks they are writing C code but they are compiling it with a C++ compiler then that is an error, and the solution is to use a C compiler instead.  I'm not so confident about how many people are in that situation, but C is **not** a subset of C++, and compiling C with a C++ compiler is inappropriate unless one is carefully and intentionally sticking to the common subset of the two languages.  That's not usually worth the effort.

Comment: As long as you're giving general advice, here's another: pointer variables that are intended to support values pointing to string literals should be declared to point to `const` data (*i.e.* `const char *text1 = "This is a string.";`).  Even though the formal type of the elements of a string literal is not `const`-qualified (per spec, for historical reasons), attempting to modify them produces undefined behavior.  Proper use of `const` and adherence to `const`-correctness is a good way to avoid that.